Locally available tool to remove broken key from lock?

Photo shows a broken key deep inside the lock.   I would like to find a tool (HomeDepot or local shop) to extract the key and salvage the lock.   If such a unicorn exists that I can buy locally: what is it called so I can Google it?

slam the lock down on a horizontal surface ... the key may pop out of the lock

Chop sticks or something similar.  I think lock picks are what you are looking for, but doubt a big box store would sell them.  Two small rods/drill bits/hex keys might be able to work it out or the vibration from a hammer/hard thing hitting it.

The tool you are looking for is a key extractor, and they come in multiple versions. A locksmith should be able to take care of this for you in a couple minutes, and if you still have the piece that broke off they may be able to use that and the extracted piece to generate a new key. Since I have sometimes seen this done deliberately as a short-term lockout, I am reluctant to say more.

that's a dirt cheap lock ... it may not be worth the effort

it can not be extracted, it is bend

try using a sewing needle as a prybar ... use a sewing machine needle because it is extremely sharp and tough, and will bite into the key

if this one of those snap-off keys for sabotaging locks or is the remains of a normal key?

@DIY75 do you mean "bent" and are you the OP? If not how can you tell it is bent or is it just your assumption?

@SolarMike you got me there, a spelling error, nice catch

@DIY75,you're probably right, because keys almost always bend a little when they snap, but it's not certain that there's a enough bend to jam it.

While it's a cheap lock, it may still be worth trying to recover (@jsotola).I have 3 like that (on various plastic garden storage containers) , keyed alike; destroying one would mean replacing them all

Do you happen to have the rest of the key still? You might manage to muscle it unlocked, at which point you have a few more options.

For a "fishing" tool, a piece of steel music wire can be bent to have the tiniest hook at the end (perhaps 200 µm, 0.2 mm). You  might need to heat the end to soften and then bend immediately, grinding off excess. BTW, music wire can have tensile strength of 30,000 kg/cm sq!

@jasen  Normal key: why pose this question?

there's a different method needed for the other thing.
